# a conductor wishes to build 9 houses, each different in

Tags: probability

a conductor wishes to build 9 houses, each different in design.in how many ways can he place these homes on a street if 6 lots are on one side of the street and 3 lots are on another side?

answer should be 2!*9! according to my knowledge

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Is this a railway conductor, an orchestral conductor, or an electrical conductor?

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem: we must choose 6 houses to be on 1 side of the street, done in $2 \cdot \binom{9}{6}$ ways (first choose the side of the street to have 6 houses, and then choose the 6 houses). The remaining 3 houses must then go to the other side of the street.

Amongst the 6 houses on one side of the street, they can be arranged in 6! ways. On the other side, with 3 houses, they can be arranged in 3! ways.

By the multiplication principle, the answer is hence:
$2 \cdot \binom{9}{3} \cdot 6! \cdot 3!=2 \cdot 9!$

So it appears that you are right.

Answer (score 0):

let n = 9 .
6 on one side and 3 on the other side gives us 6 + 3 which is 9;

> the number of permutation of n objects is n!
>   therefore the answer is 9! = 362,880